# Muliple DO command before going to the next line in txt file for Batch For /F

Tags: batch-file

I have this code in .bat file

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%G in (partners.txt) DO "C:\Program Files (x86)\iOpus\iMacros\iMacros.exe" -macro "screenshot.iim" -var_offercode %%G
ANOTHER COMMAND
```

How can I instruct the batch file to do the ANOTHER COMMAND first before getting the next input for variable %GG from partners.txt. basically, I need to complete the first cycle first before going on the next line. Currently, it finishes the list in partners.txt before moving to ANOTHER COMMAND.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a statement list in parentheses:

```
for /f %%x in (partners.txt) do (
  statement 1
  statement 2
)
```

One thing to note before you ask one of the most frequent questions as a follow-up one: Environment variables are expanded for the whole block as soon as the line is *parsed* which means if you set environment variables somewhere in that block the changes will not be visible until you step out of the loop. See `help set` for a discussion of the problem and a solution. If you need to go that route, that is.

Comment: Hi! Joey. You're right. What I missed is the "( )" and the understanding of environment variable. That did the trick. Thank you so much for jumping in and sharing your knowledge!

Comment: Hi! again. Just a follow up. I'm trying to use the same variable in the ANOTHER COMMAND but it's not rendering. 

FOR /F "tokens=* delims= " %%G in (partners.txt) DO (
"C:\Program Files (x86)\iOpus\iMacros\iMacros.exe" -macro "screenshot.iim" -var_offercode %%G
TIMEOUT /T 2
"C:\Program Files (x86)\iOpus\iMacros\iMacros.exe" -macro "screenshot2.iim" -var_offercode %%G

The second %%G is not rendering. Can you help me further? Thank you so much!

Comment: @liza: you cannot put multiple lines in a comment. In the interest of readability could you please either edit your question (or, preferrably) ask another question? I have a hard time even reading what you are doing there.

Comment: Hi Joey. You can ignore my previous comment as I've realized that it's no longer needed. Sorry also for the confusion. Anyways, can you tell how can I pass the value of %%G to CDO email in vbscript. Is that possible?

Comment: @liza: I have o clue of VBScript. Are you calling the batch from VBScript or vice-versa?

Comment: The VBscript is being called by .bat file. It's a CDO email and I would like to pass the %%G value to the body message of the cdo email which is vbscript. Thanks!

Comment: @liza: In that case simply pass it as an argument to the VBScript. You should be able to use it in the VBScript then.

Comment: Hi! again. I'm trying to use this Set ArgObj=WScript.Arguments
var1=ArgObj(0) but the script error says that "subscript out of range" any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `&` to execute multiple commands on the same line is also possible

```
for /f %%x in (partners.txt) do statement 1 & statement2
```

Comment: Hi! jeb. I've tried using the & but it continuously read the content of partners.txt which is not what I wanted. Joey's answer above did the trick... Thanks also for your time... =)

Answer (score 0):

use a batch script
for /f ... IN... do mybatchscript.bat

```
....
<mybatchscript.bat>
dosomethings
dootherthings
........
```

It SHOULD pass %1 as the parameter to the batch script from the variable in the for loop... SHOULD... because I am just speculating right now.